# Using colors with MDX calculated measure

Tags: colors, mdx

I'm using this query in MDX for a calculated measure

```
topcount(nonempty([StatusPlanes].[Status].Status.members,[Measures].[Planes]),1)(0).member_caption
```

This will bring me this result

```
Dimension1     Measure
Center 1     'Status 1' ---> i want this text blue
Center 2     'Status 2' ---> i want this text in red
Center 3     'Status 3'
Center 4     'Status 2'
```

The thing I want to do is to add some color depending on the status... is this possible in mdx?

Thank you in advance

Adriana

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT USE ALL-CAPITALS.  IT'S LIKE SHOUTING.  Please edit your question to use mixed case, like you're speaking normally.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this in your client? Are you trying to display this in SSRS, or in an application or something else?